# Weird issue with an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

**I've edited the question to be more specific and clear**

I have the following code on a standalone PHP file:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");

mysql_select_db("name", $conn);

$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM events WHERE EVENT_ID = 68")); 

var_dump($result);
```

result is `NULL`

However, if I copy the exact same query to phpMyAdmin, you can see that EVENT_PRIVATE has a value 1 in it.

[image]

I have only one db, so I'm definitely using the same db, also, if I select a different column, I can see the correct value.

I don't get it, do you?

Comment: what do `var_dump($final['EVENT_PRIVATE']);` ,`var_dump($final);` and `var_dump($result);` show? if its a boolean false or an empty string no visible output would be desired behaviour.

Comment: What do you see in phpMyAdmin if you change your query just to `SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM events ...` rather than `SELECT * FROM events...`? And what is the actual value in that column?

Comment: And `$result['EVENT_PRIVATE']` has a proper value? What does `var_dump` print?

Comment: hmm very strange can you check if field name is really EVENT_PRIVATE I mean if there is any space in the field name at the start or at the end

Comment: is that value you are expecting to see `0`?

Comment: @Samuel Herzog I updated my question, for everyone else, value in column is 1

Comment: ...and you used the same event number in your phpMyAdmin query that was in $event_id in the code? And you're definitely connecting to the same database in both cases? :)

Comment: @Matt Gibson - Yes, I also tried to replace the $event_id with 68 and displays the same info. definitely connecting to the same db in both cases.

Comment: Okay. Time to do some serious basic sanity-checking, then. Create a new, standalone php file that just connects to the database in the same way as the current code does, and does `$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM events WHERE EVENT_ID = 68")); var_dump($result)`...

Comment: @Matt Gibson - still nothing, see my last update.

Comment: Can you post the versions of PHP/MySQL that you're using (for MySQL, both the server and PHP extension versions)? You can get all the MySQL stuff from the index page of phpMyAdmin, and the PHP version from `phpinfo()`. I suspect this is probably an issue of the mysql extension (which you use) vs the mysqli extension (which is newer, more reliable, and which phpMyAdmin uses, at least in newer versions)

Comment: @Matt Gibson, @Samuel Herzog, @Spencer Hakim - Just noticed that the EVENT_PRIVATE field was set to bit, instead of int. After I changed it to int, I can see the correct value. Why couldn't I see it when it was set to bit?

Comment: @Or W: There was a bug with the mysqli extension regarding BIT columns about five years ago, it's possible a similar bug exists in the mysql extension that was just never discovered/fixed.

Comment: @Or I'm with @Spencer on this one -- just how old is the PHP and MySQL you're using? That seems like something that shouldn't be happening in current versions, but I suppose the PHP mysql extension is quite old. I don't think I've ever actually used it, because mysqli has been out since before I started using PHP...

Comment: @Matt Gibson- MySQL 5.1.41 and PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4. I don't think these are old versions, am I wrong?

Comment: did you try printing mysql_error() after the query?

Comment: There is no error, it just returns an empty value.

Comment: is it worth asking that you have checked that $conn is not null?

Comment: Yes, also if I try to retrieve a different column from that same EVENT_ID, I can see it fine.

Comment: Please try this one:$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM events WHERE EVENT_ID = '68'")); I just add single quotation around 68.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this on matching versions of PHP and MySQL, and it does seem to be something odd about the way the PHP "mysql" functions handle bit fields, or at least something I don't understand. And it certainly looks a bit like a bug. It works as I'd expect in the "mysqli" extension. Here's what I tried:

```
<?php
// mysql: 
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test');
mysql_select_db("test", $conn);
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM test WHERE id = 2'));
var_dump($result);

/* Result: 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) ""
  ["EVENT_PRIVATE"]=>
  string(1) ""
}
*/

// mysqli:
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test');
$mysqli_result = $mysqli->query('SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM test WHERE id = 2');
$result = $mysqli_result->fetch_array();
var_dump($result);

/* Result: 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["EVENT_PRIVATE"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
*/
```

EDIT: Aha!

The book ["High Performance SQL"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=mysql+fetch+bit+%22empty+string%22&source=bl&ots=CNYPArvE8T&sig=yUUerdYpztVBPQ25hsVZLS3xTQc&hl=en&ei=SHZKTYGgAtqAhAebt5nYDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) says 'MySQL treats BIT as a string type, not a numeric type; when you retrieve a BIT(1) value the result is a string but the contents are the binary value 0 or 1, not the ASCII value "0" or "1"'.

I was expecting BIT to be like the SQL Server "bit" data type, which is a single bit designed for storing a boolean true/false (0/1) value. However, in MySQL it's much more a bitfield -- unlike SQL Server, you can have a bit(8) field, for example, which is eight bits long. And MySQL has a specific "boolean" type instead for storing booleans.

I'm guessing this is the root of what's going on. Notice that what's coming back for the mysql result is a string(1) -- that's a one-character long string, *not* an empty string, which would be string(0). If you look at the value of that single character:

```
echo ord($result['EVENT_PRIVATE']); 
1
```

...then it's an ASCII 1!

So, I'd say what's happening is probably, oddly, by design. The mysql extension is being very literal about interpreting the bitfield, and giving you a string encoding the actual bits that are stored in the field in MySQL, at the bit level. The mysqli extension is being a bit friendlier, perhaps, and converting the value into a string representation of the bits.

I'll leave it to you to experiment with what happens if you grab a bit(8) set to 10101010 using mysql and mysqli...

Comment: Looks like a bug.. can't explain it in any other way.

Comment: @Or Yes, though I couldn't find it reported anywhere. But of course, the terms "php" "mysql" and "bit" are rather common in web pages! It also might be the case that most people haven't used the "bit" type with the old mysql extension -- I think "bit" was just a helpful alias for "tinyint" in earlier versions of MySQL, it's only recently that it's been a proper type in its own right...

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow your query to a single event_id. Run it on PHPMyAdmin and then via PHP. You should see the same values.

Note that the assignment to `$final` is not relevant to the question, as it cannot be flawed. The problem is in `$results`.

Answer (score -1):

replace your * with the field names to see if it complains about EVENT_PRIVATE. maybe it's not supposed to be caps or you are getting a result for the wrong join.

Comment: replaced it * with EVENT_PRIVATE, var_dump($result) shows that EVENT_PRIVATE is still empty.

Comment: echo out your sql string and run it in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT EVENT_PRIVATE FROM events WHERE EVENT_ID = '68'"));
```

I just add single quotation around 68. Let me know if it work for you.

Edit:

Just for more information about single quote and double quote in sql query you can check [THIS link](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-150508.html)